# Reading all csv lines

Tags: vlang

I was able to read the first line (which is the deader in my `csv` file) as"

```
import encoding.csv

    path:="file.csv"
    //mut f := os.read_file(path) or {println(err) return}
    f := os.read_file(path)?
    c:=csv.new_reader(f)
    r:=c.read()?

    println(r)
```

But how can I read all the lines there?

I tried:

```
    path:="file.csv"
    rows := os.read_lines(path)? 
    for row in rows {
        mut c:=csv.new_reader(row)
        mut r:=c.read()?
        println(r)
    }
```

But I got:

```sh
V panic: encoding.csv: could not find any valid line endings
print_backtrace_skipping_top_frames is not implemented
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
import os
import encoding.csv

fn main() {
    content := os.read_file('./file.csv') ?
    mut reader := csv.new_reader(content)
    reader.read() ? // Skip the first line
    for {
        line_data := reader.read() or {
            break
        }
        println(line_data)
    }
}
```

My file `file.csv` contains the following lines:

```
a,b,c
a1,b2,c3
a4,b5,c6
```

I get this result:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
['a4', 'b5', 'c6']
```

Comment: Can you explain this for me `line_data := reader.read() or {
            break
        }`

Comment: `Reader.read` returns an optional value (see the docs, unfortunately I'm on my phone so I can't link directly to the correct section, but there is a section called "Option/Result types and error handling" : https://www.github.com/vlang/v/tree/master/doc%2Fdocs.md). Here, I use the `or` way to handle errors/empty values to `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

V has not yet reached v1.0. Therefore it's to be expected that things like this won't work. It would probably be better to open an issue on the vlang GitHub repository than asking for help here.

Comment: Thanks, just agreed it there